# Caching somewhere preventing updated templates in Django 1.6

Tags: javascript, python, django, caching

Apologies for the poor title. I have a template errror when running a Django 1.6 server and accessing a particular set of templates. I've removed

> TemplateSyntaxError at /url_name 
>   Could not parse the remainder: '-name-remainder' from 'hr-name-remainder The syntax of 'url' changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.

Upon removing all references to `hr-name-remainder`

I've run

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.clear
```

the tags `{%load cache%}` do not appear in any of the templates, I've emptied the browser cache. and the same error still happens. The error happens in another browser (so isolating from any browser caching for sure?) so there is something going on in Django. I've even restarted the server multiple times.

There are no CACHE settings in my settings.py, (I should clarify that this isn't my code) and the only references to "cache" are in one of the templates where we have the following javascript

```
<script>
$(".show_filter").click(function (e) {
    $(".filter").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#search_input').autocomplete(
       {
           source: "{% url 'url_nameTWO' %}",
           delay: 50,
           minChars: 1,
           matchSubset: 1,
           matchContains: 1,
           cacheLength: 50,
           autoFill: false,
           maxItemsToShow: 10,
           onItemSelect: function(x) { $('#search_input_large').focus(); }
       }
   );
});
```

Some of the answers have asked about the exact syntax and I have changed the comments to the django template comment tags, which now look like this (one example of four)

```
  {#  <li {% block case_study_nav_class %}{% endblock %}><a href="{% url 'hr-name-remainder object.slug %}">Case studies</a></li> #}
```

Comment: This is not caching. Are you sure you have removed all the references (eg what does `grep -r "hr-name-remainder" *` show when run from your project root)? How did you restart the server?

Comment: Checked with ack-grep and all references in templates are commented. Stopped server with CTRL-C and restarted with django-admin.py runserver ...

Comment: What do you mean, "commented"? Show an example of the template.

Comment: Apologies -- typo above should read "all references in templates are commented out". As in they have <!-- --> tags around them now. So IMHO the references should no even be being read -- hence the reference about caching. When I comment out code I do not expect it to then throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation about comments reveals your problem. Django doesn't care about HTML comment tags and will continue to parse template tags inside comments. If you need to convent things out in a template, you should use Django comment tags, eg `{# ... #}`.

Of course you would be better off fixing the actual problem, which is fully explained in the docs pointed to by the error message: put the URL name in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for that. I went down the commenting route as all the urls are >1.5 compliant already, and I have been warned that this error can be due to an upstream issue, so I was attempting to isolate it. I have now changed the tags to {# ... #} as suggested but the problem still persists.